# how to alternate foreach statements PHP

Tags: php, foreach

How do I alternate these foreach statements in the sense that after one result of the first foreach statement is echoed one result from the second foreach statement will be echoed? Here are the two foreach statements.

```
 foreach($anchors as $a) {
    $text = $a->nodeValue;
    $href = $a->getAttribute('href');
$i++;

if ($i > 16) {
    if (strpos($text, "by owner") === false) {
     if (strpos($text, "map") === false) {


          echo "<a href =' ".$href." '>".$text."</a><br/>";


     }
    }
  }

  }


foreach($span as $s) {
echo "<br>".$s->nodeValue."<br>" ;

}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking, but you might want to try using `continue;`, which will restart the foreach at the next item once a condition is met.

Comment: If PHP had an array zip function and the ability to use `list` in `foreach` it would be nice here. (e.g., `foreach(array_zip($anchors, $spans) as list($a, $s))`) Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Literally you cannot "merge" two foreach statements, but you can use each() function as workaround. Place this somewhere in first cycle:

```
list(,$s) = each($span);
echo "<br>".$s->nodeValue."<br>" ;
```